# Java - object for loop with condition?

Tags: java, iterator, conditional-statements, break

This may sound silly but I couldn't find an answer by googling it.

When using a for loop in it's simplest form I can add conditions to break the loop in the for statement. example:

```
for(int i=0; i<100 && condition2 && condition3; i++){
    //do stuff
}
```

When using an object for loop like this:

```
for(String s:string_table){
    //do stuff
}
```

how can i add a condition to break the loop? I'm talking about adding conditions in the for statement. I know I can add the condition inside //do stuff part and break from there.

Comment: You can't do that... The foreach construct is "fixed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that you have to go by putting the if statements in the for loop.

Comment: that's too bad. it would make it much easier

Comment: @user3051067 It wouldn't. It would just make it one line shorter. If it upsets you that much, put the if-break on the same line as the opening brace and pretend it's part of the for syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add anything else to the `()` part of the "enhanced for" statement. [JLS § 14.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14):

> The enhanced for statement has the form:
>
> `for ( FormalParameter : Expression ) Statement`
>
> The type of the *Expression* must be `Iterable` or an array type.

(The "FormalParameter" means a variable declaration.)

The `break;` statement is the only way:

```
for (String s : string_table) {
    if (condition) break;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: +1. Now can you please explain why did you choose this avatar? :D

Comment: I would use `if (!condition2 || !condition3) ...` instead of `if (condition)` to match OP's code better.

Comment: @Boann That's the last thing that I though about LOL.